# Phonegap File System 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, filesystems, fileapi

I have mobile web app that runs on iOS. 
I run JS code that is served from a remote server. in it, I call window.requestFileSystem and it evaluates as 'undefined'.

However, when evaluating this from a bundled .html file (located in the www folder of the xcode project) it IS defined.

How do I access Phonegap file system API from a remote JS code?

Answer (score 0):

a couple things -

1. This WILL not be accepted to the app store, as Apple not cool with
   an app that downloads executable code.
2. The reason you're unable to run this code is because it's being loaded in later - which in theory shouldn't be an issue, but I would put my money on the fact that even though it has the correct calls, its not being counted as a part of your actual application.